# Are tags exclusive to one image in a Docker repo?

Tags: docker, docker-tag

I thought that tags in Docker worked like in stackoverflow where millions of questions can be tagged with the same tag. But when I tag a second image in Docker the first one loses its tag:

[image]

So are images to tags one-to-many, i.e. one image can have multiple tags in a repo, but a tag cannot be applied to 2 or more images in the same repo?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show the actual command(s) you ran and what they output, as text?  I can't really tell what that PNG file is trying to show.

Comment: If you're familiar with Unix hard links and the `ls -i` command, then a better analogy would be that a Docker `repository/image:tag` name is like a file name pointing at a numbered image; only one image can have a given `repository/image:tag` at a time, but an image can have multiple names, or none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pushing a new tag replaces the old tag, but if you know the digest, you can pull the old manifest until the registry garbage collects it.

A tag is a pointer to a manifest in the registry, and it can only point to a single manifest, similar to a symlink in Linux. This is needed since everything else in the registry is content addressable, so you need the tag to avoid needing to remember long digests.

There are a couple manifest types, an image manifest, and a manifest list. The manifest list contains references to other manifests, which is commonly used for multi-platform images. So a tag pointing to a manifest list could refer to multiple images using a manifest list. But runtimes will only pull a single image out of that list. And that list is generated by the tool pushing the image, not dynamically created by the registry by merging the previous images into a list (that would break the content addressable logic since it would change the digest).

Comment: That makes sense. So docker tags are more like a git branch or a git tag - since git is also content-addressable.

Comment: @sashoalm A git tag would be a good comparison. There's a lot shared between the two designs.